# It is possible to traceroute without touching ICMP?

Tags: unix-sockets, traceroute, icmp

I often run into a situation where I want to traceroute an IP without root or NET_RAW cap in Linux.

I have attempted to send a UDP packet with a small TTL but no ttl error is emitted at all. It seems that getting the TTL exceeded error requires using an ICMP socket. Is it possible to use UDP or TCP protocol only without involving ICMP while still getting notified for TTL error so that I can traceroute with limited capabilities?

Comment: Please defined OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, you can use any protocol.
Try [tcptraceroute](https://github.com/mct/tcptraceroute).

Or the standard [traceroute](http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/).

from man page:

> ```
>    -I, --icmp
>           Use ICMP ECHO for probes
>
>    -T, --tcp
>           Use TCP SYN for probes
>
>    -U, --udp
>           Use UDP to particular destination port for tracerouting (instead
>           of  increasing  the  port  per  each  probe). Default port is 53
>           (dns).
>
>    -UL    Use UDPLITE for tracerouting (default port is 53).
>
>    -D, --dccp
>           Use DCCP Requests for probes.
>
>    -P protocol, --protocol=protocol
>           Use raw packet of specified protocol for  tracerouting.  Default
>           protocol is 253 (rfc3692).
> ```

Comment: Traceroute needs always raw sockets no matter the operating mode AFAIR

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro https://stackoverflow.com/a/23119894 .  `cp $(which traceroute) . && ./traceroute google.com` works fine for me as an unprivileged user.  (The `cp` proves this is not due to set-uid root).

Comment: (on Linux).  Oh, and for setting the TTL, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31066364 .  Regarding this answer, note that `traceroute --tcp` *does* require root.  It is UDP traceroute that Linux lets you do without privilege.

Comment: @sourcejedi Interesting, it seems I am a bit outdated here. Thanks.